# Handle multiple push provider with Exact Target sdk

Tags: mobilepush-android

According to the documentation http://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/JB4A-SDK-Android/trouble-shooting/multiple-push-sdks.html
We can use the following method to know if a push was from ExactTarget or from any other provider.

```
PushMessageManager.isMarketingCloudPush(bundle)
```

But in the latest SDK (5.4.2), this method has been moved from this interface and obfuscated into another class.

```
salesforce.marketingcloud.messages.push.a.a(bundle)
```

Why this is not available publicly any more? and what's the alternative method?
I can of course use the source in my own code like

```
public static boolean isMarketingCloudPush(@NonNull Bundle bundle) {
        return bundle != null && (bundle.containsKey("_m") || bundle.containsKey("_nodes"));
    }
```

but would be nice if SDK provides the method itself.

Answer (score 1):

There was a refactor to that class in the 5.4.x release and that method was missed as being part of the public interface.  I will log a bug to get that corrected, but in the meantime, you can just do the `bundle.containsKey("_m")` check before passing the Bundle into the PushMessageManager.